# Event tracking for a certain field of a form

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

Is it possible to specify the goal of the event tracking to a certain field of a form, such as selection from dropdown list or check box having been checked?

I have a variable product which is generated by a field of my form.

then, i created a function calTrack();

```
var Product;

function calTrack(Product)
    {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form',Product]);
    }
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

sure.  just bind events to the elements you want to listen to, then call your tracking function.

ie:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
<option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mySelect').change(calTrack); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: obviously, this assumes the use of jquery but the same thing can be accomplished in native JS or through another framework

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try native js, i have hybrid both of them too much...